# Error that contract is not convertible to expected type address

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment

In older solidity compilers this code snippet works. In newer compilers, I get an error. Can someone what I need to change so it works again? I get the following error message: "Type contract createWallet is not implicitly convertible to expected type address. I extracted the snippet so it is easier to see my problem.

```
contract factorywallet { 

   function newWallet(uint256 _unlockDate) public returns(address wallet){
        wallet = new createWallet(msg.sender);
    }
}





contract createWallet{
    address public owner;

    constructor(address _owner) public {
        owner = _owner;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use an explicit cast:

```
wallet = address(new createWallet(msg.sender));
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be address(new createWallet(mag.sender))?

Comment: That's better, yes. Edited. (Both work.)

Comment: Cool, didn't know the first way of casting worked as well